# Create splitscreen video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor

I have two videos of different length. I need to create a new video with one video at the left and other at the right. I tried using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233833/267627). Problem is my videos are of different length. I want to start one video a few seconds after the other started. Also, I want to keep the audio of the longer video only.

Comment: Do you know which of the videos is longer?

Comment: Yes. I know. The right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i shorter.mp4 -i longer.mp4 -filter_complex
 "[0]trim=0:3.5,drawbox=c=black[delay];[delay][0]concat[left];
  [left][1]hstack[v]"
 -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:a copy out.mp4
```

where `3.5` should be replaced with the delayed start time (in seconds) of the shorter video.

Comment: Awesome! But there was one missing point. Sync was proper. But the right video didn't start until the delay (13s) elapsed. Then both videos started simultaneously. In essence, I lost the first 13s of the right video

Comment: See edited cmd.

Comment: No. The update distorted. Both videos began simultaneously. After few seconds, left video paused for few seconds. Then it resumed in sync with the right video

Comment: Show full log..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gaX3d2ccbUcNjS8TqIPBL1kRX-sB4z0y

I have put the logs here

Comment: You're using an older version of ffmpeg which needs manual buffering. Change first line of filters to `[0]trim=0:3.5,drawbox=c=black,fifo[delay];[delay][0]concat,fifo[left]`

Comment: Got an Error
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vgDD6T0HlR7BBaUHLdybBzlfBQnJNqyx

I installed ffmpeg today from here http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.4.1.tar.bz2. I'm running on macbook pro
Do, I need to install something else also?

Comment: Get a binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71182/discussion-between-nagabhushan-s-n-and-mulvya).

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -i left.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=0:13,drawbox=c=black:t=fill[delay];[delay][2]concat[left];[left][1]hstack[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:a copy out.mp4` with the new binary. This is an outstanding buffer mgmt issue.

Comment: Error again! 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fRWw03VP-GlCtDJOgHcWgs5dXUnRlb4t

Comment: What's the output of `ffmpeg -hide_banner -filters`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13vBYu8M9wsiGXsJBTqgTB977sM7K2hlC

Comment: It shows the concat filter. Rarely, there's a character coding issue when pasting to/from Stack Exchange. Retype the command at your end and run.

Comment: Yes. Its working perfectly fine now. Thanks a lot!
Also, I have one more request. A small extension. How to handle the below scenario. Left video should start after right video. But the length is such that left video extends after the right video ends. The current command handles this, but after right video ends, audio stops. Left video continues without audio. How to make such that after right video ends, audio should be taken from left video?
Should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: Ask a new Q. It's more convoluted to switch audio like that.

Comment: I have asked here. https://video.stackexchange.com/q/23156/21062
Thanks!